# ORA-00942 in Jobs

Tags: oracle

I am trying to write a trigger that grants certain rights to a role after creation on certain users. So I wrote a trigger which makes a job to grant that rights(since you can't create grants directly in the trigger.
My trigger looks like this

```
create or replace TRIGGER ops$test2.grant_on_creation
  AFTER CREATE ON DATABASE
DECLARE
  v_jobno PLS_INTEGER;  
  v_cnt number(1);
  v_stmt varchar2(4000);
BEGIN
  select count(*)
    into v_cnt
    from DBA_ROLES
   where role = 'ROL$'||substr(ora_dict_obj_owner, 5);
  if ora_dict_obj_owner like 'OPS$%' and v_cnt=1 and ora_dict_obj_type in ('SEQUENCE', 'PROCEDURE',  'PACKAGE',    'VIEW', 'TABLE', 'FUNCTION') then
    select 'grant '||decode(ora_dict_obj_type, 'SEQUENCE', 'SELECT', 'PROCEDURE', 'EXECUTE',  'PACKAGE', 'EXECUTE', 'VIEW', 'SELECT', 'TABLE', 'SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE, INSERT', 'FUNCTION', 'EXECUTE') ||
       ' on '||ora_dict_obj_owner||'.'||ora_dict_obj_name||' to ROL$'||substr(ora_dict_obj_owner, 5)
      into v_stmt
      from dual;
       dbms_job.submit( v_jobno,
                   'declare v_errm varchar(4000); 
                   BEGIN 
                     execute immediate '''||v_stmt||'''; 
                   exception 
                    when others then 
                      v_errm := SQLERRM ; 
                      insert into ops$test2.AT_TEST_GRANT values(v_errm); 
                      commit; 
                   END;',
                   sysdate + interval '10' second );
  end if;
END;
/
```

ops$test2 should have all the necessary permission, but when I create a table in another schema, I get ORA-00942: table or view does not exist (in my AT_TEST_GRANT -table)

LOG_USER, PRIV_USER and SCHEMA_USER of the Job is ops$test2.
When I just take the exact code from the job and execute it with my user ops$test2 it just works fine.

Comment: When you create the table in another schema, how does ops$test2 have permissions to grant priviliges on that new table on behalf of the table owner? GRANT ANY OBJECT PRIVILEGE would be needed for ops$test2 I would imagine, and I would guess it would probably need to be directly granted and not just via a role?

Comment: The user has DBA rights. Like I said, it works, when I execute it in Toad but it doesn't work when I make a job, that does exactly the same.

Comment: When the job runs, as far as I know any ROLES the user has is not in effect. So I think role DBA is not active when the job runs. Try granting GRANT ANY OBJECT PRIVILEGE to the user directly in addition to the DBA role.

Comment: Thanks that worked. I was just confussed of which privilege you are talking about, since i didn't get you have to write two grant in a row: "GRANT GRANT ANY OBJECT PRIVILEGE  TO OPS$TEST2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed "GRANT GRANT ANY OBJECT PRIVILEGE TO OPS$TEST2" like  Kim Berg Hansen suggested